# Frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black) doesn't

Tags: java, swing, colors, jframe, jpanel

I've followed the advice of countless other tutorials for changing the background color of a JFrame, but I haven't any luck. Here's my code for initializing and creating a frame

```
package frameTests;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Foo extends JPanel {

public static void frameInit(Foo foobar){
    // window initialization
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Spaceship Defenders!");
    frame.add(foobar);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);// center frame in screen.
}




public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

    Foo bar = new Foo();
    frameInit(bar);

    }
}
```

[image: And here's the resulting Frame, with the default grey background]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your panel `foobar` is hiding the `ContentPane`. Either make the panel transparent or set the color of the panel itself to [`BLACK`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#BLACK)

```
foobar.setOpaque(false);
```

Comment: Perfect! I hadn't thought about the panel's transparency. Thanks!

Comment: @fostythesnowman If this answer helped you solve your problem, then help everyone out and mark it as correct.  This will prevent the other volunteers here from reading a question and sifting through code if the answer has already been supplied.